# Is my laptop hardware sufficient to install & run Ubuntu as a secondary OS smoothly?

Tags: laptop, hardware

I have a Asus laptop which is running Windows 7. Its a first gen core i3 with a 500gb hdd & 6gb of ram. I would want to install Ubuntu as a secondary OS on my laptop. I asked a friend of mine whether my laptop can run Ubuntu smoothly when installed. He told me that my laptop hardware spec isn't good enough & my laptop will experience performance problems if I install Ubuntu. I just want to get a second opinion. Will it really affect my laptop performance if I do install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 even on machines with an ancient Celeron and Pentium IV, 512MB RAM, and a 40GB hard drive. Even if you had a 14 year old desktop, you could at least run Lubuntu 14.04 on it just fine.

See recommended specs on the Ubuntu Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

I'm good with an older machine - Use the Ubuntu live USB, and click 'try without installing' which will load the system into memory so that you can get a feel for how all the devices work.